# jQuery unordered list element click selector issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a part of a web app view, the user enters in some data and it is added to an unordered list.  For future modification, I want to have each list element selectable for edit and/or review.

HTML:

```
<div id = "answer_list_container">
  <ul id = "answers">
    <li id = "answer_1" class = "answer">Answer1 Text</li>
    <li id = "answer_2" class = "answer">Answer2 Text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

However, I can't get right selector for the list element.  I've tried

- $("#answers > li").click(answerSelectionHandler);
- $(".answer").click(answerSelectionHandler);
- $("#answers li").click(answerSelectionHandler);

`answerSelectionHandler` contains a `console.log` call that fires on execution of the handler.  It is not going off, which suggest a selector issue.

Comment: Is the console.log at the top of the function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing the `li` elements are added dynamically so you need to delegate on the closest static parent element like this

```
$('#answers').on('click','.answer',function(){
   answerSelectionHandler();
});
```

Comment: I forgot about `on()`, since I was so used to using `click()`.  Too bad the standard event functions don't have implicit functionality of `on()`